# ApiVersion inheritance

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have such code in AspNetCore 1.1.2

```
[ApiVersion(Versioning.V2)]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public abstract class ApiController : Controller
{
}

public sealed class AwesomeController : ApiController
{
    [Route(""), HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Hello from 2.0";
    }
}
```

When running the application I obviously receive `UnsupportedVersion` because `ApiVersionAttribute` is not inherited.
I understand that if I move `[ApiVersion(Versioning.V2)]` to `AwesomeController` everything will work, but I have a pretty big structure of my controllers per version (let say 15) and would like to inherit them from single controller of specific version to have a single place to add my service bus imports and etc.

Is there any gentle way to achieve such requested behavior?

p.s. I strongly don't wan't to adjust `IActionSelector`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out that the best approach is to adjust the `ApplicationModel` metadata by using the own custom `IApplicationModelConvention` implementation where you can specify new `ControllerApiVersionConventionBuilder` and apply to those controllers that were marked up with `NeutralVersionApiVersionModel` but don't have any `[ApiVersion]` supplied. Also `ApiVersionConvention` maybe needs to be removed from setup in order to stop marking controllers with default version (see more here https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/blob/a15fe09917b35c648b8ef5e53c44f05c5b9134ed/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning/Versioning/ApiVersionConvention.cs#L96)